# Stuck on Derivation of Chebyshev's Estimates for $\pi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, distribution-of-primes

I am trying to develop a simple derivation of Chebyshev's estimates for the prime counting function $\pi(x)$.

Stopple's *"A Primer of Analytic Number Theory"* gives a good start:

By considering the following

$${2n \choose n} = 2n \cdot (2n-1) \cdot (2n-2)\cdot \ldots \cdot (n+2) \cdot (n+1) $$

He explains that there are $\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$ primes in this quantity. He also shows without too much effort that:

$$ n^{\pi(2n)-\pi(n)} < {2n \choose n} < 2^{2n}$$

He then takes logs to give:

$$ \boxed{\pi(2n)-\pi(n)< \frac{2n\log(2)}{\log(n)}}$$

This is very promising. Intuitively this hints at $\pi(n)$ being of the form $n/\log(n)$.

**Question: How does one solve the above for $\pi(n)$ ?**

And in general, how does one solve for $f(x)$ when faced with the following?
$$ f(2x) - f(x) = g(x) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$f(2x)-f(x) = g(x)$
then
$f(2x/2^k)-f(x/2^k) = g(x/2^k)$.

Summing,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)-f(1)
&=\sum_{1 \lt k \le \log_2(x)}f(2x/2^k)-f(x/2^k)\\
&= \sum_{1 \lt k \le \log_2(x)}g(x/2^k)\\
&\lt \sum_{1 \lt k \le \log_2(x)}\dfrac{2\log(2)(x/2^k)}{\log(x/2^k)}\\
&=2x\log(2) \sum_{1 \le k \lt \log_2(x)}\dfrac{1/2^k)}{\log(x)-k\log(2)}\\
&=\dfrac{2x\log(2)}{\log(x)} \sum_{1 \le k \lt \log_2(x)}\dfrac{1}{2^k(1-k\log(2)/\log(x))}\\
\end{array}
$

and once we show that
the sum is bounded,
we are done.